# nslcd authentication is failing with error "lookup failed: No results returned" for ldap users

Tags: linux, bash, ldap, pam, nss

I am using nslcd service to authenticate ldap user during SSH login and it is failing with below error

**nslcd: [16231b]  uid=omc,ou=people,ou=accounts,dc=netact,dc=net: lookup failed: No results returned**

Below is the nslcd debug logs during ldap user login,

```
nslcd: [b127f8] <passwd="omc"> DEBUG: ldap_initialize(ldap://10.91.149.148/)
nslcd: [b127f8] <passwd="omc"> DEBUG: ldap_set_rebind_proc()
nslcd: [b127f8] <passwd="omc"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3)
nslcd: [b127f8] <passwd="omc"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_DEREF,0)
nslcd: [b127f8] <passwd="omc"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT,0)
nslcd: [b127f8] <passwd="omc"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMEOUT,0)
nslcd: [b127f8] <passwd="omc"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT,0)
nslcd: [b127f8] <passwd="omc"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,LDAP_OPT_ON)
nslcd: [b127f8] <passwd="omc"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_RESTART,LDAP_OPT_ON)
nslcd: [b127f8] <passwd="omc"> DEBUG: ldap_simple_bind_s("uid=nea7yxpm,ou=people,ou=accounts,dc=netact,dc=net","***") (uri="ldap://10.91.149.148/")
nslcd: [b127f8] <passwd="omc"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): uid=omc,ou=people,ou=accounts,dc=netact,dc=net
nslcd: [b127f8] <passwd="omc"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results (1 total)
nslcd: [16231b] DEBUG: connection from pid=7465 uid=0 gid=0
nslcd: DEBUG: accept() failed (ignored): Resource temporarily unavailable
nslcd: DEBUG: accept() failed (ignored): Resource temporarily unavailable
nslcd: DEBUG: accept() failed (ignored): Resource temporarily unavailable
nslcd: DEBUG: accept() failed (ignored): Resource temporarily unavailable
nslcd: [16231b] <authc="omc"> DEBUG: nslcd_pam_authc("omc","sshd","***")
nslcd: [16231b] <authc="omc"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="ou=people,ou=accounts,dc=netact,dc=net", filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=omc))")
nslcd: [16231b] <authc="omc"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): uid=omc,ou=people,ou=accounts,dc=netact,dc=net
nslcd: [16231b] <authc="omc"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="uid=omc,ou=people,ou=accounts,dc=netact,dc=net", filter="(objectClass=*)")
nslcd: [16231b] <authc="omc"> DEBUG: ldap_initialize(ldap://10.91.149.148/)
nslcd: [16231b] <authc="omc"> DEBUG: ldap_set_rebind_proc()
nslcd: [16231b] <authc="omc"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3)
nslcd: [16231b] <authc="omc"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_DEREF,0)
nslcd: [16231b] <authc="omc"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT,0)
nslcd: [16231b] <authc="omc"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMEOUT,0)
nslcd: [16231b] <authc="omc"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT,0)
nslcd: [16231b] <authc="omc"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,LDAP_OPT_ON)
nslcd: [16231b] <authc="omc"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_RESTART,LDAP_OPT_ON)
nslcd: [16231b] <authc="omc"> DEBUG: ldap_simple_bind_s("uid=omc,ou=people,ou=accounts,dc=netact,dc=net","***") (uri="ldap://10.91.149.148/")
nslcd: [16231b] <authc="omc"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results (0 total)
nslcd: [16231b] <authc="omc"> uid=omc,ou=people,ou=accounts,dc=netact,dc=net: lookup failed: No results returned
nslcd: [16231b] <authc="omc"> DEBUG: ldap_unbind()
```

Below is the nslcd.conf:

```
root@NthlrAtca07> cat /etc/nslcd.conf
binddn uid=nea7yxpm,ou=people,ou=accounts,dc=netact,dc=net
bindpw l0T%OSUe_7m_1~F
tls_reqcert allow

uri ldap://10.91.149.148/
base ou=people,ou=accounts,dc=netact,dc=net
tls_cacertdir /etc/openldap/cacerts
map    passwd loginShell       "/usr/bin/bash"
map    passwd homeDirectory    "/home/$uid"
```

Below is nsswitch.conf:

```
root@NthlrAtca07> cat /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# An example Name Service Switch config file. This file should be
# sorted with the most-used services at the beginning.
#
# The entry '[NOTFOUND=return]' means that the search for an
# entry should stop if the search in the previous entry turned
# up nothing. Note that if the search failed due to some other reason
# (like no NIS server responding) then the search continues with the
# next entry.
#
# Valid entries include:
#
#       nisplus                 Use NIS+ (NIS version 3)
#       nis                     Use NIS (NIS version 2), also called YP
#       dns                     Use DNS (Domain Name Service)
#       files                   Use the local files
#       db                      Use the local database (.db) files
#       compat                  Use NIS on compat mode
#       hesiod                  Use Hesiod for user lookups
#       [NOTFOUND=return]       Stop searching if not found so far
#
# To use db, put the "db" in front of "files" for entries you want to be
# looked up first in the databases
#
# Example:
#passwd:    db files nisplus nis
#shadow:    db files nisplus nis
#group:     db files nisplus nis
passwd:     files ldap
shadow:     files ldap
group:      files ldap
#initgroups: files
#hosts:     db files nisplus nis dns
hosts:      files dns
# Example - obey only what nisplus tells us...
#services:   nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#networks:   nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#protocols:  nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#rpc:        nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#ethers:     nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#netmasks:   nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
bootparams: nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
ethers:     files
netmasks:   files
networks:   files
protocols:  files
rpc:        files
services:   files
netgroup:   files ldap
publickey:  nisplus
automount:  files ldap
aliases:    files nisplus
root@NthlrAtca07>
```

Below is PAM policy:

```
root@NthlrAtca07> cat /etc/pam.d/password-auth
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 500 quiet_success
auth        sufficient    pam_ldap.so use_first_pass
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_access.so
account     required      pam_unix.so broken_shadow
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 1000 quiet
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_ldap.so
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass retry=3 authtok_type= difok=3 dcredit=-1 ocredit=-1 ucredit=0 lcredit=0 minlen=8 maxrepeat=1 maxsequence=4 reject_username
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so md5 shadow try_first_pass use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_ldap.so use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
-session     optional      pam_systemd.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
session     optional      pam_ldap.so
```

I see the setup is rightly configured, even then nslcd is failing to authenticate the ldap user. Could you please help here.

Comment: You're wasting your reputation on the wrong platform. Your question is better suited to [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/tour) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: What happens when you execute the same query with ldapsearch on the command line originating on the same host, with the same connection and authentication mechanisms (this might be hard to get exactly right) and the same credentials? Does it return anything else than an empty result? If yes, please show the exact ldapsearch call with all arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all who gave a thought about this question.

I found out the real issue:

It was identified that login and group issue was due to ACI (Access Control List) implemented in LDAP servers. 
Also user "uid=nea7yxpm,ou=people,ou=accounts,dc=netact,dc=net" used in nslcd.conf was not having read access and hence during authentication the above ACI rules were preventing ldap user to access there own information hence authentication was failing.

To resolve this, ACI rules were added to have read permission to the user and authentication was successful.